# unzip task overwrites target files

Tags: ant, unzip

```
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html - Unzip takes overwrites target files even when overwrite is given as false. What would be the problem here?

<unzip src="MathJax.zip" dest="${appserver.deploy}/ROOT.war" overwrite="false"/>
```

appserver.deploy - points to the appserver deploy folder.

Comment: Can you give us the ANT script you are using to do the unzip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [this discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@ant.apache.org/msg37483.html) on `ant unzip` and `overwrite` parameter.  It looks like `overwrite` will **always** happen if timestamp in the archive is newer than that in the destination.  The discussion offers a workaround for this.

Comment: I guess the timestamp is the issue for me, is there a way to override this.